# How String to Timestamp works without explicit conversion in oracle where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Both of following SQL works in my Oracle DB, the result or the count of results are completely same and correct. CREATE_TIME is a timestamp column.

```
select * from EMPLOYEE where CREATE_TIME =(or >) '2022-01-21 2:49:38.251'
select * from EMPLOYEE where CREATE_TIME =(or >) '22-01-21 2:49:38.251000'
```

Quite curious on how it works because the String format is different, I didn't use TO_* conversion function and the Oracle NLS(as default conversion rules) shows completely different format.

```
PARAMETER -> VALUE
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT -> DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT -> HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT -> DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_FORMAT -> HH.MI.SSXFF AM
```

Searched the information but didn't find the answer, it would be appreciate if anyone could answer me and provide a information/document link for reference.

Comment: Review this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ  ... The more recent documentation should contain this information as well.  Like this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1

Comment: In principle (and this will also be relevant to the rest of my comment), this is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5 For example, if your format model includes `RR` but you have a four-digit year, Oracle will try `RRRR` instead. With that said, I don't believe you. To be clear: I think you didn't show us the real values either of your data or of your NLS parameters; you are just making it up. (continued below)

Comment: `MON` requires an alphabetic "month"; Oracle will substitute `MONTH` if given `AUGUST` with the format `MON` - and even the format `MM`; but it will NOT accept a numeric value if you give the format `MON`. Also, it will not use `2022` as the first date element, if your format model has `DD` first (as your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` does). What you reported is not true.

Comment: Are you sure about the NLS settings? They are defined on database, instance and session level.

Comment: Got the NLS settings by using this SQL, and I only showed the NLS_TIME* items in the description.
`SELECT parameter, value FROM nls_database_parameters`

Comment: I see... Tried the `SELECT parameter, value FROM nls_session_parameters` and the result changed. It became `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF`

Comment: OK - for **that** value of `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` the answer is my first comment above. In it I explained both what is happening and where you can find specific documentation of that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to perform an explicit cast using `CAST(value AS TIMESTAMP)`, or an equivalent implicit cast such as in your query, from the string values to a timestamp then Oracle will implicitly convert the cast to the equivalent of:

```sql
TO_TIMESTAMP(
  value,
  (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT')
)
```

---

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '2022-01-21 2:49:38.251'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '22-01-21 2:49:38.251000' FROM DUAL;
```

You can see it in action using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF';

SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(
         CAST(value AS TIMESTAMP),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'
       ) AS converted_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs the error:

> ```
> ORA-01843: not a valid month
> ```

As, given the [string-to-date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5)  the `MON` format model will also match `MONTH` but it will not match the numeric `MM` format so the `01` month generates the error.

However:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF'

SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(
         CAST(value AS TIMESTAMP),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'
       ) AS converted_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | CONVERTED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2022-01-21 2:49:38.251 | 2022-01-21 02:49:38.251000 |
> | 22-01-21 2:49:38.251000 | 2022-01-21 02:49:38.251000 |

Both the rows are converted as expected.

---

If, instead, you use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF'

SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(
         CAST(value AS TIMESTAMP),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'
       ) AS converted_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Then the output is:

> | VALUE | CONVERTED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2022-01-21 2:49:38.251 | 2022-01-21 02:49:38.251000 |
> | 22-01-21 2:49:38.251000 | 0022-01-21 02:49:38.251000 |

And the first row converts as expected but the second row the `YYYY` format model matches `22` and gives 22 AD rather than 2022 AD (as was probably expected).

---

If you want to compare to a timestamp then either use an explicit conversion:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   EMPLOYEE
WHERE  CREATE_TIME = TO_TIMESTAMP(
                       '2022-01-21 2:49:38.251',
                       'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF'
                     )
```

Or a timestamp literal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   EMPLOYEE
WHERE  CREATE_TIME = TIMESTAMP '2022-01-21 02:49:38.251'
```

If you rely on the NLS parameters then your query may have different (and unexpected) behaviours for different sessions (sometimes even for different sessions of the same user).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f496cf34b1453e7bb56ea66e56b8d739)*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description.@MT0 A further question that I'm curious what determines the nls_session_parameters? In my Oracle DB it is different from nls_database_parameters and I don't remember I've set it.

Comment: @Allen.Chen I believe that the documentation you want to refer to is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tdddg/working-in-global-environment.html#GUID-7C40C91D-FEC9-4454-B385-B4344CA16FC3).

Comment: @Allen.Chen - the NLS parameters can be set at different levels, and there is an order of priority. For example the session parameters (which you can change during a session, with the `alter session` statement), if they are defined, override the database values. Values given explicitly in a call to `to_timestamp` (if you use that, instead of allowing Oracle to make an implicit conversion) have the highest priority. Documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html#GUID-6475CA50-6476-4559-AD87-35D431276B20